# How to expose the return type of a global class method?

Tags: oop, abap

I've written an ABAP Method, which returns me some analyses in a custom table.
Now I want to call this Method from an RFC module.

So far so good - the method works fine, but I'm curious of how to return this table?
Do I have to create a table / structure ... in `SE11` to make it work because otherwise I can't refer to this table type or is there an easier way?
I'm quite new to `ABAP` so I don't know the best practices.

```
m_analyses = new zcl_manalyses(  ).
data(lt_m_analyses) = m_analyses->analyse_m_data(
    budat_from  = budat_from
    budat_to    = budat_to
).
```

[image]

Comment: Expose the table type as a class type?

Comment: @JonasWilms how to do that?

Comment: Are you asking how to return a table via the Web service? Like XML, JSON format? And so the question is how to convert the internal table to XML or JSON?

Comment: @SandraRossi no - i know how to return the table via web service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TYPES` statement can not only occur inside a method's body, but also [inside the class definition](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenclass_component.htm), in which case it can be accessed from other places with `class_name=>type_name` (if it's public):

```
CLASS cl_user_registry DEFINITION PUBLIC.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
   TYPES:
     BEGIN OF user,
       firstname TYPE string,
       lastname  TYPE string,
     END OF user,
     users TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF user.

   METHODS:
     get_current_users
       RETURNING users.
ENDCLASS.

DATA current_users TYPE cl_user_registry=>users.
current_users = cl_user_registry=>get_current_users( ).
```

Answer (score 2):

You first have to create a structure in `ABAP Dictionary` (`SE11`), then you create a table type in `SE11` as well.

You then reference the structure in the line type of the table type.

Try using the new global table type, it should work. (with typing '`TYPE`')

Comment: Thanks - it worked that way. 
Then I'll do it like that in the future, but I think it's kind of annoying to always create a structure/table just for returning it. :D